# Hibernate: Getting data for One to Many Mapping

Tags: java, hibernate

A table `Product` represents two entities `Parent` and `Child`.There relationship is defined in a separate table, lest's say `Relation_Table`.

hbm for Product is very straightforward. It does not have any reference to `Reference_Table`. hbm for `Relation_Table` looks like this:

```
<class name="RelationMember" table="RELATION_TABLE" lazy="true">
  <id column="relation_id" type="int"/>
  <many-to-one name="parent" class="Product" column="pId"/>
  <many-to-one name="child" class="Product" column="child_id"/>
</class>
```

How would I fetch all the `children` for a given `pId` of a parent?

Is it like first I will fetch list of `child_id` and then use that list to read all entities from `Product` table?

Wondering if Hibernate provide some ways of mapping `child_id` directly to fetch entities from `Product` table.

Answer (score 0):

You did not inlclude your classes but in typical cases, JPQL query is like:

```
select child from Product child where child.parent.id in :pids;
```

but Hibernate will still translate it to 2 joins, Product x Relation_Table x Product again.

You can use native query to have only 1 join (Product x Relation_Table).
But since the joins will be index based joins, you can trust DB to run it fast and there is no need for this extra optimization.